# Problema com o código da extensão Chrome

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extensão

Boa tarde!

Estou tentando criar uma extensão para clicar automaticamente em um botão de uma página a cada X segundos. No meu caso é uma ferramenta de trabalho chamada ServiceNow, onde tem painéis com relatórios em tempo real, porém o menu onde ficam os chamados que tenho que atender não atualiza sozinho, apenas se clicar em um botão com ícone de Refresh.

O problema é que ele não executa a função que deveria (acredito que seja problema no **querySelector**).

**`div do botão`**

```
<div class="header-tools" style="background-color: #1d7f00">
<button tabindex="0" class="btn header-icon icon-refresh" style="color: #FFFFFF" aria-label="Atualizar Widget Dashboard Fila Atendimento - Incidentes" title="" data-original-title="Atualizar"></button>
</div>
```

**`manifest.json`**

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "Auto Refresh - ServiceNow",
"description": "Extensão para o Google Chrome que atualiza automaticamente o ServiceNow.",
"version": "1.1",
"icons": {
"128": "128.png"
},
"content_scripts": [{
"matches": ["https://renner.service-now.com/*"],
"js": ["autorefresh-servicenow.js"]
}]
}
```

**`autorefresh-servicenow.js`**

```
;(function( doc ) {
  'use strict';
  
  console.log( "Auto Refresh - ServiceNow" );
  var $autorefreshsn;
  
  window.setInterval(function() {
    var $autorefreshsn = document.querySelector('button.btn.header-icon.icon-refresh::before');
    if( ! $autorefreshsn ) {
        return;
    }
    
    $autorefreshsn.click();
  }, 3000);
})( document );
```

> **Obs:** Já tentei sem o `::before`, tentei só com a class `.header-tools` e até pelo atributo `[style="background-color: #1d7f00"]` mas nada adiantou.

Answer (score 4):

O problema é o seletor mesmo, se verificar o retorno dele é `null`. Você pode usar como seletor:

`button[aria-label="Atualizar Widget Dashboard Fila Atendimento - Incidentes"]`

```js
(function(doc) {
  'use strict';
  
  const query = 'button[aria-label="Atualizar Widget Dashboard Fila Atendimento - Incidentes"]'

  window.setInterval(function() {
    var $autorefreshsn = doc.querySelector(query);
    if (!$autorefreshsn) return;
    $autorefreshsn.click();
  }, 3000);

  // Só para logar quando ocorrer clique no botão. :)
  document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log('Fui clicado...')
  })
})(document);
```

```html
<div class="header-tools" style="background-color: #1d7f00">
<button tabindex="0" class="btn header-icon icon-refresh" style="color: #FFFFFF" aria-label="Atualizar Widget Dashboard Fila Atendimento - Incidentes" title="" data-original-title="Atualizar">Botão</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Show! E como faço para selecionar com o atributo também? No caso o mesmo que eu coloquei ali. Existem 5 botões desse na página, 4 deles nos painéis que são real-time (wtf?) e mais esse que fica pra atualizar o Dashboard. Eu teria que selecionar ele em específico e a única distinção é o style="background-color: #1d7f00".

Comment: @RogerWindberg o `aria-label` e `data-original-title` são iguais em todos?

Comment: O ```data-original-title``` são iguais em todos porém o ```aria-label``` é único para cada um.

Comment: @RogerWindberg pode fazer a consulta por ele então, editei a resposta.

Comment: @RogerWindberg uma dica: se você precisa fazer uma interação com a página que não necessita utilizar nenhuma API de "baixo nível" que extensões usam, é mais simples criar um userscript do que uma extensão. Até como exemplo, tenho um script para resgatar pontos de canais automaticamente na Twitch (que é basicamente a mesma coisa que o seu script faz): [exemplo](https://github.com/rn4n/AutoRedemptionOfTwitchPoints/blob/main/auto-redemption-of-twitch-points.user.js)

Comment: Tentei de tudo aqui com as dicas mas mesmo assim não funcionou, parece que ele não reconhece o selector de jeito nenhum. O objetivo de criar uma extensão é para eu conseguir "corrigir" essas falhas da página e conseguir compartilhar com a equipe de trabalho depois.

Comment: Um userscript também pode ser instalado por várias pessoas e versionado. Quanto a questão do seletor, da pergunta que você fez, o que dá pra responder é isso.

Comment: Entendi. Sou bem leigo nesse assunto de programação e essa é minha primeira tentativa de montar um código. Como funciona esse userscript? Não faço ideia de onde aplicar e o que fazer com ele.

Comment: @RogerWindberg no readme desse link que te passei, tem uma explicação de como instala um userscript.